# How to decide whether or not to implement SCIM endpoint

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, active-directory, scim, microsoft-identity-platform

This question is asked in the context where a company wants to implement a new SaaS solution with a REST API plus a single-page web-application on top of it,

where authentication and authorization and also user management are to be implemented using Microsoft Identity Platform and Microsoft Azure Active Directory.

I am wondering if in such a scenario, an own SCIM (2.0) endpoint is needed at all, or if perhaps simply a user management API (which itself may or may not be SCIM compliant) of Microsoft Identity Platform or Microsoft Azure Active Directory can be used for user management, so that users would only be stored and managed within AD for now.

Comment: Are you developing a multi-tenant SaaS application or are you using a SaaS application from another company and building on top of it?

Comment: The former, we are developing a multi-tenant SaaS application.

Answer (score 0):

Baseline expectations for multi-tenant SaaS applications nowadays include user provisioning functionality. SCIM 2.0 is the only widely adopted modern standard for internet-based provisioning. Your options are therefore going to be to implement your own proprietary user/group management APIs or implement SCIM 2.0. If you're looking for support from major identity providers (AAD, Okta, etc..) then SCIM 2.0 is likely the only standard that any identity provider will build against.

TL;DR: SCIM 2.0 is the way to go.